# Replace instead of append in java pattern matching?

Tags: java, regex

Currently, this code appends the pattern match to the string buffer after each line it finds a match. However, I want to pattern match and replace 2 different patterns, and the program is printing out duplicates of the lines where it finds both of those patterns since it appends each line it finds a pattern match. Is there any way to just print out the final line with the replacements? I think I might have to change the append to a replace in the first pattern matcher, but I do not know any methods that would do that.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    RealReadFile file = new RealReadFile();
    while (!file.endOfFile()) {
        String line = file.nextLine();
        Pattern cpochhammer = Pattern.compile("(\\(([^)]+)\\)_\\{([^}]+)\\})");
        Matcher pochhammer = cpochhammer.matcher(line);
        StringBuffer rplcmntBfr = new StringBuffer();
        while(pochhammer.find())  {
           pochhammer.appendReplacement(rplcmntBfr, "\\\\pochhammer{$2}{$3}");
        }
        pochhammer.appendTail(rplcmntBfr);
        Pattern npochhammer = Pattern.compile("(\\(([^)]+)\\)_(.))");
        Matcher ppochhammer = npochhammer.matcher(rplcmntBfr);
        while(ppochhammer.find())  {
               ppochhammer.appendReplacement(rplcmntBfr, "\\\\pochhammer{$2}{$3}");
            }
            //ppochhammer.appendTail(rplcmntBfr);

        System.out.println(rplcmntBfr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you set the `rplcmntBfr` into the matcher between the first and second replacement loops, you must clear out the buffer with

```
rplcmntBfr.setLength(0);
```

Otherwise, while you are correctly replacing the value of `rplcmntBfr` in the second loop, its result is being *appended* to the result of the first replacement, which is not correct. The result of the next replacement needs to ***replace*** the contents of `rplcmntBfr`.

Comment: but if I clear out the contents of the buffer after I set the matcher, the second replacement loop does not have any content to replace/append from. There is a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException when I run it.

Comment: Try "Matcher ppochhammer = npochhammer.matcher(rplcmntBfr. ***toString()*** );"

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem. Why does it work with a toString() though?

Comment: toString creates a new object. Without it the original is being pointed to. I didn't think toString would be necessary, actually, but obviously it is. Glad it worked.